# How to pass variable from controller to blade in loadView of dynamic DOMPDF in sending mails?

Tags: laravel, dompdf, laravel-mail, laravel-dompdf

Instead of 'john' I want to replace it using the selected user's name from database. Is there a way to this on Mail? 
**Controller**

```
public function sendEmail(Request $request)
{
    $users = StudentApplicants::whereIn("id", $request->ids)->get();
    $data = [
        'name' => 'john'
    ];
    $pdf = app('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadView('admin.send-awardees-certificates.certificate', $data);
    $pdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

    foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
        Mail::to($user->users->email)->send(new CertificateEmail($user, $pdf));
    }
    return response()->json(['success' => 'Send email successfully. Refresh the page']);
}
```

**Mail**

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->from(env('info@example.com'))
        ->subject('Certificate from ABC EFG')
        ->view('email.certificate-email') //body
        ->attachData($this->pdf->output(), 'stock_report.pdf');
}
```

**Certificate Blade**

```
<div class="name">
    {{ $name }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accept the user as constructor parameter

```
public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

then pass it to the view like this

```
$this->view('email.certificate-email')
     ->with([
         'user' => $this->user
     ]);
```

I think this [section in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#view-data) will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I have found the answer, I should have put the $data array and $pdf = app... ,$pdf->loadView...,,$pdf->setPaper inside the foreach.